# Content Scroll using native javascripts in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have a div with **style="height:100% ; width:35%;"** and when i change the size of the browser window the content in the div are overflow and i want to place the container in the div that can be easily fill and want to move other to other page using pagination.

[div pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PByCf.png)

I am doing this in order to get the number of images that can be place in the container and how do i paginate it using native javascripts.

```js
(function() {
  var getPreviewContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('previewContainer')[0];
  var getPreviewParent = document.getElementsByClassName('previewParent')[0];
  var PreviewParentWidth = getPreviewParent.clientWidth;
  var heightOfPreviewParent = getPreviewParent.clientHeight;
  var PreviewContainerWidth = getPreviewContainer.clientWidth;
  var heightOfPreviewContainer = getPreviewContainer.clientHeight;
  var differenceBetweenPerviewWidth = PreviewParentWidth - PreviewContainerWidth;
  var getBlueBox = document.getElementsByClassName('previewImgContainer')[0];
  var d = getBlueBox.clientWidth;
  var heightOfBlueBox = getBlueBox.clientHeight;
  var blueBoxWidth = d + 23;
  var blueBoxHeight = heightOfBlueBox + 23;
  var numberOfBlueBox = Math.floor(PreviewContainerWidth / blueBoxWidth);
  var numberOfVerticalBox = Math.floor(heightOfPreviewContainer / blueBoxHeight);
  console.log(numberOfVerticalBox + ' ' + 'can be placed in this height')
  console.log(numberOfBlueBox + ' ' + 'can be placed in this width');
  var spaceTakenByBlueBox = blueBoxWidth * numberOfBlueBox - 23;
  var e = PreviewContainerWidth - spaceTakenByBlueBox;
  var paddingReqired = e / 3;
  getPreviewContainer.style.marginLeft = paddingReqired + differenceBetweenPerviewWidth;
})();
```

This function align the content to center and tell how many boxes can be placed in the size that the container have i also want to paginate how i will do that

Comment: could you please create a fiddle ?

Comment: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/asifjavedg3/kw53hgzy/

Comment: @ShailendraSharma will you do my favor?

Comment: i am here to solve problems and errors people are facing, not for writing code for them